# RoR - Randomise Video to play on homepage

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, video

Trying to serve a random video on each time a user either comes to the website or refreshes the homepage. This will allow it to look different and refreshing each time.

**Current code for the home.html**

```
<div class="home-banner basic-banner static video-container hidden-xs hidden-sm">

    <%= @random_video %><%= video_tag "test-3.mp4, test-4.mp4", autoplay: true, loop: true, muted: true, class: "video" %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title text-center">
            <h1 class="border border-color-white border-thick">PARADISE<br>BELOW</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Videos are coming from /app/assets/videos/

**Static Controller**

```
  def home
    @tour_category = TourCategory.all
       @videos  = ["app/assets/videos"]
       @random_no = rand(2)
       @random_video = @videos[@random_no]
  end
```

The random functions works, although it only displays the title of the video on on load or refresh. example: test-3.mp4 , refresh : test-4.mp4

So now its only to get the videos to play correctly instead of showing the title.

Been looking at this for help: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Rails/Displayrandomimage.htm

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is straightforward to the solution, but you have to fix 3 points:

- Your random logic does not work as you think. Your `@videos` just an array of string `"app/assets/videos"`, not array of files
- You should use `video_tag` with your random-ed video. Since you use it with `"test-3.mp4, test-4.mp4"` string, that why it generated a wrong video HTML.
- The `video_tag` need video file name, not file, so again your random logic did not solve it.

To achieve the result,

- Your random logic should look like

  ```
  videos = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos/*.mp4")
  random_video_path = videos.sample
  @random_video_name = File.basename(random_video_path)
  ```
- And use it in your view

  ```
  <%= video_tag @random_video_name, autoplay: true, loop: true, muted: true, class: "video" %>
  ```

Rails will do the rest for you, including generating the correct video URL.